# Stackdriver Monitoring with full access scope not authorized

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver

After deploying a brand new Google Compute Engine instance with full API access and installing the Stackdriver agent, the Monitoring is not showing any metrics from the agent.

According to the [Install Agent](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/install-agent) manual no further settings (like manually configurating an API key) should be required.

The agent service status also shows the following error:

```
$ systemctl status stackdriver-agent
Jul 13 10:14:00 host stackdriver-agent[21203]: [  OK  ]
Jul 13 10:14:00 host systemd[1]: Started LSB: start and stop Stackdriver Agent.
Jul 13 10:14:00 host collectd[21226]: Initialization complete, entering read-loop.
Jul 13 10:14:00 host collectd[21226]: match_throttle_metadata_keys: 1 history entries, 1 distinct keys, 46 bytes server memory.
Jul 13 10:14:00 host collectd[21226]: tcpconns plugin: Reading from netlink succeeded. Will use the netlink method from now on.
Jul 13 10:14:00 host collectd[21226]: write_gcm: Asking metadata server for auth token
Jul 13 10:14:01 host collectd[21226]: write_gcm: Unsuccessful HTTP request 403: {
                                               "error": {
                                                 "code": 403,...
Jul 13 10:14:01 host collectd[21226]: write_gcm: Error talking to the endpoint.
Jul 13 10:14:01 host collectd[21226]: write_gcm: wg_transmit_unique_segment failed.
Jul 13 10:14:01 host collectd[21226]: write_gcm: wg_transmit_unique_segments failed. Flushing.
```

Google Cloud Console shows the instance having:

```
Cloud API access scopes
This instance has full API access to all Google Cloud services.
```

and running the following command inside the instance shows:

```
$ curl --silent -f -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google" http://169.254.169.254/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/scopes
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform
```

Any thoughts on what is going wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured it out:

You have to [enable](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/cloudmonitoring.googleapis.com) the `Google Monitoring API` in the `API Manager`, which is not enabled by default. No need to specify an API key, the default application credentials are picked up.

Interestingly, I have two projects which also use Stackdriver Monitoring since early this year and those do *not* require the Google Monitoring API to be enabled.

Comment: I've had this too, my guessing is that vms that were created recently check whether the api is enabled, for older vms the check may be skipped???

Comment: Enabling Google Cloud Monitoring API was the answer for me as well. I was not able to browse to it in the "API Manager" webapp, I had to search for it, which brought me to this link https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/cloudmonitoring.googleapis.com/overview As @Jaap said, this is only happening for older VMs. Still, this fix was preferable to rebuilding the VM. Thank you both.